# Modal Dialog Box with Facebook app shows only over iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to show jquery-ui modal dialog box in my iframe facebook app, but it disables the iframe area within the facebook app i.e. it is modal only for the iframe and I can click other facebook elements outside of iframe. What I want instead is to disable the entire page then just the iframe.

The version of jquery used is 1.5.1, jquery-ui is 1.8.10 and the code is

html

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
    <p>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
   </p>
   <p>
      Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
   </p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function() {

         $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                 modal: true,
                 buttons: {
                      Ok: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
              }
          });
  });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since your app resides in the iFrame you cannot take control over the parent iframe since it lives on a separate domain.  I your app requirements dictate you must put your dialog over everything, then I would suggest you change from use a canvas app and build a web site app instead.  Very easy to do, I have a few of them running in production.

Comment: I am in advanced stages of development and I am not sure if I move from canvas app to web site app what effect will it have on my existing code. From documentation it seems for websites one can only use facebook social plugins and of course Graph API in the backend. Moreover changing my iframe app to website app might be overkill just to solve the problem in hand.

Comment: Standalone websites can also use Javascript SDK in addition to the social plugins.  Without seeing your code I could only guess as to what the effects are.  What in an iFrame are you using that would not be available to you in a non-canvas situation?